# OnClick widget changes text of widget

Tags: widget

Can someone please tell me what onclicklistener to use for a widget in appwidget provider.

When user clicks on widget the view must change.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use onUpdate in the widgetProvider for that:(this would open taskmanageractivity in this case)

```js
 @Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
   int[] appWidgetIds) {
   for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
     int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskManagerActivity.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

     RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
     views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, pendingIntent);
     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
   }
 }
```